# Удалить из textbox строки - удовлетворяющие подстрокам из списка

Tags: c#, winforms

Это работает, но как сделать более эффективней ?
Нужно из `textBox multiline` - удалить строки, в которых есть подстрока из списка.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxLines.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < spisok.Count; x++)
            {
                if (textBoxLines[i].Contains(spisok[x]))
                {
                    textBoxLines[i] = "";
                }
            }
        }

        textBox2.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < textBoxLines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (textBoxLines[i] != "")
            {
                textBox2.AppendText(textBoxLines[i]);
            }

        }
```

Comment: 1. как минимум можно прерывать внутренний цикл, если уже совершено очищение подстроки. А вы зачем то продолжаете сравнивать очищенную строку с оставшимися подстроками

Comment: 2. не проводил бенчмаркинг, но думаю взаимодействие с визуальными элементами нужно свести к минимуму. Выполняйте AppendText один раз для заранее сконкатенированных результатов

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov Спасибо!

Comment: @StanislavPechezerov, а вот как заранее подготовить файл правильно для вставки ? В почищенном массиве будут такие значения "" присутствовать. Я же не могу их удалить и уменьшить массив. Как вариант - у меня в голове крутилось - то что не подходит под проверку из списка - добавлять сразу в новый лист) - но потом уперся - то что лист нельзя разом вставить в textbox xD

Comment: `textBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, textBoxLines.Where(l=>spisok.All(s=>!l.Contains(s))));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я внес изменения, указанные мной в комментариях:

```
    // используем StringBuilder для предварительной конкатенации за пределами textBox2
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxLines.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < spisok.Count; x++)
        {
            if (textBoxLines[i].Contains(spisok[x]))
            {
                textBoxLines[i] = "";
                // прерываем цикл, предотвращая дальнейшее сравнивание, если строка уже очищена
                break;
            }
        }

        // сосредоточим все действия в одном цикле
        if (textBoxLines[i] != "")
        {
             s.AppendLine(textBoxLines[i]);
        }
    }

    textBox2.Text = s.ToString();
```